# CSS is not linked to HTML

Tags: css, html

I'm not sure how to link CSS to the HTML. Here's how I link currently:

```
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

But when I do so and save it, I don't see any changes, so I've resorted to using the `<style>` tag. I'm also using Sublime Text if that has anything to do with the issue:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    background: green;
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>`
```

Comment: Have you verified the path is correct?

Comment: No, I honestly have no experience in this type of work in anyway at all. Kinda just sat down at computer saw a vid talking about it and went at it, do i need to put my main.css file in the same folder as my html documents or?

Comment: What's your directory structure? Did you check the developer tools to see if the resources successfully loaded?

Comment: The way it is now you should have a styles folder wherever your HTML file is and inside that folder should be your main.css file.

Answer (score 0):

Try an absolute path.

Change:

`<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

to

`<link href="http://yourwebsite.com/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

If that doesn't work please edit your question to include the contents of your `main.css` file as this may be a simple misunderstanding on how to write a stylesheet.

Happy coding.

Comment: relative paths are generally preferred due to making the code more portable.

Comment: @Don I agree but I figured for debugging purposes if it still failed with an absolute path then there may be an issue elsewhere possibly in the `CSS` file itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

As written, your main.css file has to be in a subfolder called "styles", relative to your html document.

Here is the structure visualised:

[image]

If you had the main.css file in the same folder, you could change the link tag to be:

```
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and right click the **main.css** and open it in a new tab. If the file can't be displayed, the path is probably wrong

Comment: In the future state the answer more like an answer and not another question. Also an improvement would be to give more general instructions to discover if the path is indeed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated it's likely that the path is wrong. Try appending that path to the url of the html page, minus the html file.

eg: `http://www.mysite.me/index.html` becomes `http://www.mysite.me/styles/main.css`

If the css file doesn't come up then your path is incorrect.

---

If your css file includes the `<script>` and `</script>` that is your issue. The CSS file should only include the style sheet text, and those tags are for entering a style sheet inside the HTML and not using a link as you seem to want to do (props to you ;))

The content of your main.css file should look exactly like:

```
body {
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
  }
```